Error in email preview when using Lookup() with _subscriberkey
I'm new to SFMC and AMPScript. I want to create an email that starts with the name of the employee who receives it, using the Lookup() function to return their name.
My code:
%%[ SET @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") SET @name = Lookup("Employees", "name", "employeeId", @subKey) ]%% %%=v(@name)=%%
But it doesn't work. The _subscriberkey matches with the primary key of the data extension "Employees". The PK is "employeeId".
When I simply test with:
%%[ SET @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") ]%% %%=v(@subKey)=%%
it works!
My problem is when I use the lookup:

I need to return the name of the employee. How can I do that? Please, I need your help :)

Is there a name field in the Employees data extension?

Yes, Employee data extension has a "name" field which I use in the Lookup:
Lookup("Employees", "name", "employeeId", @subKey)

From the screenshot of your error message it seems there is some unwanted html added inside your AMPscript.
Try using a code snippet block for the AMPscript or make sure you edit your AMPscript in the text version of the content block you are using.
Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_create_code_snippet.htm&language=en_US&type=5
